# Trying to get 3840x2160@60Hz working. Macbook Air M2, Sharp PN-K321 "4K" monitor. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: displayport, 4k

I'm hoping someone can help. I'm trying to get my Macbook Air M2 working at 3840x2160@60Hz with my new to me Sharp PN-K321. I can get 3840x2160, but only at 30Hz.

Things I've tried:

- 2 different brand usbc to displayport cables from amazon, both
  advertised as supporting 4K@60hz
- a usbc to HDMI cable advertised as supporting 4K@60Hz
- In monitor menu switching dipsplayport mode to MST: this just gave me
  1920x1080@60Hz
- Reset monitor to factory settings

I don't really know where to go from here, any advice?

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment since it doesn't solve this, but perhaps it gives some further ideas on how to figure it out. There's a site with compatible screens for a lot of models: https://tonsky.me/blog/monitors-mac/ . They focus on 120Hz+ but perhaps it's still insightful somehow

Comment: FWIW, I just got a Macbook Air M2 and it will only work with my external monitor at 30Hz. Mine is an LG 34UC98-W. I've hooked up other Apples and Windows machines without issue.